# C++ Character battle code issue

Tags: c++, pointers, object, reference, instantiation

So I have this code that should just basically create objects and then send them to an 'arena' which outputs a string of text via cout. The issue I'm having is in my main is when I try to send the created objects in I'm getting an error and I could use some explanation so I understand what I did/am doing wrong. I understand (for the most part) about using objects, but I get a little confused when I start to use the *. The problem I am getting is in the myGame.cpp at the line that say Engine->arena.

Code:

Engine.h

```
#ifndef ENGINE_CLASS
#define ENGINE_CLASS

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Engine
{

public:
    Engine();
    ~Engine();
    void arena(Character*, Character*);

};

class Character
{

private:
    string m_name;

public:
    Character();
    ~Character();
    virtual void fight();
    virtual string getName();
    virtual void setName(string);

};

class Gladiator : public Character
{

public:
    Gladiator();
    ~Gladiator();
    virtual void fight();
    virtual string getName();
    virtual void setName(string);

};

class Monster : public Character
{

public:
    Monster();
    ~Monster();
    virtual void fight();
    virtual string getName();
    virtual void setName(string);

};

#endif
```

Engine.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Engine.h"
using namespace std;


//Methods for Engine Class
Engine::Engine()
{

}

Engine::~Engine()
{

}

void Engine::arena(Character *oCharacter1, Character *oCharacter2)
{
    //Logic
    oCharacter1->fight();
    oCharacter2->fight();
    //More Logic
}

//Methods for Parent-Charachter Class
Character::Character()
{
    m_name = "Unknown";
}

Character::~Character()
{
    m_name = "";
}

void Character::fight()
{
    cout << "Fight" << endl;
}

string Character::getName()
{
    return m_name;
}

void Character::setName(string newName)
{
    m_name = newName;
}

//Methods for Child-Gladiator Class
Gladiator::Gladiator()
{
    Character::setName("Maximus");
}

Gladiator::~Gladiator()
{
    Character::setName("");
}

void Gladiator::fight()
{
    cout << "Maximus strikes monster..." << endl;
}

string Gladiator::getName()
{
    return Character::getName();
}

void Gladiator::setName(string newName)
{
    Character::setName(newName);
}

//Methods for Child-Monster Class
Monster::Monster()
{
    Character::setName("Monster");
}

Monster::~Monster()
{
    Character::setName("");
}

void Monster::fight()
{
    cout << "Monster strikes Maximus..." << endl;
}

string Monster::getName()
{
    return Character::getName();
}

void Monster::setName(string newName)
{
    Character::setName(newName);
}
```

myGame.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Engine.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    //Instantiation
    Engine engine;
    Character *aCharacter1;
    Character *aCharacter2;

    //Association
    aCharacter1 = new Gladiator;
    aCharacter2 = new Monster;

    //Fight
    Engine->arena(*aCharacter1, *aCharacter2);

    //Cleanup
    delete aCharacter1;
    delete aCharacter2;

}
```

***UPDATE***

Now upon taking the corrections into consideration, I get the following 4 errors

```
Error   1   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Character'  c:\users\christopher\desktop\paul\school\neit\game architecture\week 4 & 5\christopher-midtermpart2\christopher-midtermpart2\engine.h   13  1   Christopher-MidtermPart2

Error   3   error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Character'  c:\users\christopher\desktop\paul\school\neit\game architecture\week 4 & 5\christopher-midtermpart2\christopher-midtermpart2\engine.h   13  1   Christopher-MidtermPart2

Error   4   error C2511: 'void Engine::arena(Character *,Character *)' : overloaded member function not found in 'Engine'   c:\users\christopher\desktop\paul\school\neit\game architecture\week 4 & 5\christopher-midtermpart2\christopher-midtermpart2\engine.cpp 18  1   Christopher-MidtermPart2

Error   2   error C2660: 'Engine::arena' : function does not take 2 arguments   c:\users\christopher\desktop\paul\school\neit\game architecture\week 4 & 5\christopher-midtermpart2\christopher-midtermpart2\mygame.cpp 19  1   Christopher-MidtermPart2
```

Comment: Unless this is academic, you should not use raw pointers in modern C++, better use refs, `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: Undefined behavior when you call `delete` on your objects.  Your base class destructor is not declared as `virtual`.

Comment: `arena` is an instance method. You cannot call it on a class. It's `engine.arena`, not `Engine->arena`

Comment: Also, `arena` takes pointer, so you must pass pointers, not dereferenced values: `engine.arena(aCharacter1, aCharacter2)`.

Comment: Why are you allocating objects using `new` when you don't need to?  Declare them in `main` similar to declaring an integer variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your `void arena(Character*, Character*);` method takes poiters to Characters, but you are trying to pass actuall objects poited by pointers:
`Engine->arena(*aCharacter1, *aCharacter2);`
Change this line to
`Engine->arena(aCharacter1, aCharacter2);`
or change your method, so it can take objects as arguments instead of pointers:
`void arena(Character, Character);`

Also, as `Giulio Franco` mentioned:
`arena is an instance method. You cannot call it on a class. It's engine.arena, not Engine->arena`, and as `PaulMcKenzie` mentioned:
`Undefined behavior when you call delete on your objects. Your base class destructor is not declared as virtual`

Answer (score 0):

1) Declare your `Character` destructor as `virtual`.

The reason why is that in `main`, you are deleting pointers to derived objects through a base class pointer.  Once you do that, the base class must have a destructor declared as `virtual`, else the behavior is undefined.

So you need to have this:

```
virtual ~Character();
```

and then in `main`, this now has defined behavior:

```
//Cleanup
delete aCharacter1;
delete aCharacter2;
```

---

2) You have to pass pointers to the `arena` function, not objects.

```
engine.arena(aCharacter1, aCharacter2);
```

Comment: Engine is a class and arena is a non-static member function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie good catch on the virtual. I forgot to put that in there for the destructor. I have to get in a better habit of putting that in there.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Now upon building I get errors. Will update the main thread with the problems.

Comment: Engine uses Character, but Engine has no idea what a `Character` is.  Move the definition of `Character` before `Engine`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Agh  I see. Because it's trying to utilize something that technically hasn't been created yet, it will freak out. I appreciate your help, I understand this a bit better. I have some issues when it comes to using pointers and *.